# Receiving new classes over a network

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I'm writing something that will be receiving new types of objects. Before it gets these objects I send over the class file of these new types. When I read in the new objects a ClassNotFoundException is thrown unless the class file is in the applications running classpath (bin folder).

I would like to save my class files somewhere else on the system (Windows). I have looked into using a custom classloader but have not been able to use one successfully. The easier solution  would appear to be just adding another location/classpath to look for the class files. But adding the location to the Windows CLASSPATH variable doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll ultimately need to use a `ClassLoader` to do something like this, regardless of how you're injecting your classes (over the network or touching the filesystem).

However, there are libraries that will handle this for you, [Jodd](http://jodd.org/doc/add-classpath-in-runtime.html) in particular will handle this. According to the docs, if you're getting the class bytes over the network, you can add the class with a one-liner:

```
Class c = ClassLoaderUtil.defineClass("MyNewClass", classBytes);
```

See: [`ClassLoaderUtil.defineClass()`](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/jodd/util/ClassLoaderUtil.html#defineClass%28byte%5b%5d%29)

This will hide the `ClassLoader` details from you, but using the `ClassLoader` to do what you want - pulling class bytes over the network - is pretty easy. You should post specific problems that you're having here, with some of your code, and someone should be able to give you a useful answer, and then you won't need another library.

Comment: Thank you! The ClassLoaderUtil from Jodd makes this very simple.